# Mongoose: Upsert document with $sum

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a document that looks like this:

```
var TestSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    userId: Number,
    date: Date,
    usage: Object
});
```

When I insert something into the database, that document can look like:

```
{
    userId: 10,
    date: 2015-11-12,
    usage: {
        foo: 12,
        bar: 5
    }
}
```

Now is it possible to upsert this document, where usage uses the $sum of the new document and the old document?

So when I do `findOneAndUpdate`, I basically only want to add up the usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator is applicable only to the aggregation framework via the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator pipeline stage and can only return a sum on each grouped field (not multiple fields). What you need is the [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#exp._S_add) arithmetic operator and the specific operation you want can't be done with an atomic update, you'd need two operations to do this: an aggregation which adds up the old field with the new object and then the **[findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** operation.

Consider the following operations which will ultimately produce the desired update:

```
var newUsageObj = {
    "foo": 8,
    "bar": 15
},
query = { "userId": 10 };

// Using the mongoose aggregation builder
Model.aggregate()
     .match(query)
     .project({
         "updatedUsage": {
             "foo": { "$add": [ "$usage.foo", newUsageObj.foo ]},
             "bar": { "$add": [ "$usage.bar", newUsageObj.bar ]}
         })
     .exec(function (err, res){
         if (err) return handleError(err);
         res.forEach(function (doc){
             Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, { "usage": doc.updatedUsage }, options, callback);
         });
     });
```

Read the **[Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)** docs for more information.

Comment: Sorry about the late response to this, but this worked perfectly.
The only change I made was that findAndUpdate didn't seem to create a new record.

Comment: @woutr_be Great to hear that. Did you specify the option `{upsert: true}` in your `findAndUpdate` method? That option inserts a new record.

Comment: Something I didn't consider before, what if my `newUsageObj` doesn't contain `foo`, during the `aggregate` it will remove that. Is there any way to resolve this?